# How to get list of "colleges" based on preferences nearby using google place api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have worked with the google place api and hence i know how to work with it to get the basics but how do i get the list of `colleges` nearby because google place api doesn't have that tag yet, they have `school`, moreover it doesn't provide me the link that i want to filter.

The filters should be based on the following:

1. the result should return what type of college is it (either `private or govt.`, `engineering or medical`)
2. minimum eligibility criteria
3. location(`this i can get`)
4. the fee

So i want to know is there a way to retrieve all these data from the `http` request? As i have tried with the field as `school` and i haven't received the following except location of course or `how does college search websites work?`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lng,lat&radius=5000&types=school&sensor=true&key=........
```

But `google map`does give the following result when we google for `colleges`

Comment: Hi, how your going to retrieve the information like fees or type of college is it?Is your perform it by google place api?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "university" tag if you only want colleges. However, [the JSON response](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchResponses) does not include information like application fees or what type of college it is (at least not yet):

> Each result within the results array may contain the following fields:
>
> - icon contains the URL of a recommended icon which may be displayed to the user when indicating this result.
> - id contains a unique stable identifier denoting this place. This identifier may not be used to retrieve information about this place,
>     but is guaranteed to be valid across sessions. It can be used to
>     consolidate data about this place, and to verify the identity of a
>     place across separate searches. Note: The id is now deprecated in
>     favor of place_id. See the deprecation notice on this page.
> - geometry contains geometry information about the result, generally including the location (geocode) of the place and (optionally) the
>     viewport identifying its general area of coverage.
> - name contains the human-readable name for the returned result. For establishment results, this is usually the business name.
> - opening_hours may contain the following information:
>
>   - open_now is a boolean value indicating if the place is open at the current time.
> - photos[] — an array of photo objects, each containing a reference to an image. A Place Search will return at most one photo object.
>     Performing a Place Details request on the place may return up to ten
>     photos. More information about Place Photos and how you can use the
>     images in your application can be found in the Place Photos
>     documentation. A photo object is described as:
>
>   - photo_reference — a string used to identify the photo when you perform a Photo request.
>   - height — the maximum height of the image.
>   - width — the maximum width of the image.
>   - html_attributions[] — contains any required attributions. This field will always be present, but may be empty.
> - place_id — a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. To retrieve information about the place, pass this identifier in the
>     placeId field of a Places API request. For more information about
>     place IDs, see the place ID overview.
> - scope — Indicates the scope of the place_id. The possible values are:
>
>   - APP: The place ID is recognised by your application only. This is because your application added the place, and the place has not yet
>       passed the moderation process.
>   - GOOGLE: The place ID is available to other applications and on Google Maps.
>
>   Note: The scope field is included only in Nearby Search results and Place Details results. You can only retrieve app-scoped places via
>     the Nearby Search and the Place Details requests. If the scope field
>     is not present in a response, it is safe to assume the scope is
>     GOOGLE.
> - alt_ids — An array of zero, one or more alternative place IDs for the place, with a scope related to each alternative ID.
>
>   Note: This
>     array may be empty or not present. If present, it contains the
>     following fields:
>
>   - place_id — The most likely reason for a place to have an alternative place ID is if your application adds a place and receives
>       an application-scoped place ID, then later receives a Google-scoped
>       place ID after passing the moderation process.
>   - scope — The scope of an alternative place ID will always be APP, indicating that the alternative place ID is recognised by your
>       application only.